# Can I use only numbers for naming a CSS class

Tags: css

I want to know whether numbers(only) can be used for naming a css class

is this valid?

```
.2{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not valid. 
But the more important fact is that you shouldn't define classes with no meaning as that doesn't make any sense when looking at writing semantic markup.

> In CSS1, a class name could start with a digit (".55ft"), unless it
>   was a dimension (".55in"). In CSS2, such classes are parsed as unknown
>   dimensions (to allow for future additions of new units) To make "2x" a
>   valid class, CSS2 requires the first digit to be escaped ".\32x" [2x]

[CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator)

Comment: what about .2x{display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, it throw the selector rule exception. its like declaring a variable in c or cpp... if u declare as 2 then its not a variable, its a constant. because int num=2; this is always correct form but string 2=num; is always wrong in programming.
Read more from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use only numbers as a css3 class name. but check this link out.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

No not possible

you can use like

```
._2{
}
or like 

.a2{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No,it's not working.

a lot of language is not support the first word is number.

Maybe you can use `.menu-1`